# Left part of image is much softer than the right part: decentered lens or bad M42-EOS adaptation?

Tags: lens, lens-adapter

The problem mentioned in the title, i.e. 'left part of image is much softer than the right part', is clearly demonstrated in the image below.

[image]

It is less obvious when it 'focuses' at the centre of the image:

[image]

The images came from Canon 550D with a Helios 44-2 lens @F2.0.

I read the uneven sharpness across the imaging could be caused by [lens decentering](https://photographylife.com/what-is-a-decentered-lens/), but I'm also wondering if it could be caused by the adaptor.

This Helios 44-2 is the newest version of its kind. The problem with this version of the lens is that the surface of the M42 thread flange is flush with the back end of the focus ring, as can be seen from the image below:

[image]

My worry is if the surface of the flange is slightly lower than the back end of the focus ring, the M42-EOS adaptor may come into contact with the focus ring, which effectively increases the distance between the sensor and the lens, and I do feel a little bit harder to turn the focus ring with the adaptor attached.

So, what do you think? Is this lens decentred or it could be the adaptation?

---

**Update**

Here's some 100% crops of two other images I took this morning against the test chart.

Focused

[image]

Defocused

[image]

These images show the four large black & white tiles arranged around the star pattern in the test chart. The purpose of this is to do a 'flare' test similar to what Roger Cicala suggested in his [blog post](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2012/05/testing-for-a-decentered-lens-an-old-technique-gets-a-makeover/) (Thanks @MichaelClark for this link).

According to Roger:

> if the lens is decentered or significantly tilted the center blur will ‘flare’ out in one direction or another as you defocus.

In the defocused image, a substantial amount of flare can be seen in the tile blocks in the top left and nearly invisible in those in the bottom right. This might suggest the lens is probably indeed decentred or tilted.

Is this still possible the adaptor plate to blame?

Comment: It could also be as simple as the optical axis of the lens not being perpendicular to the test chart.

Comment: @MichaelClark, I was aware of this. I have actually tried shooting at the chart with another Heliso 44-2 at the same spot and posture, and the result was a fine image.

Comment: *"same spot and posture"* Posture ?  That suggests you're testing hand-held, which is just asking for problems like this.  Are you testing hand-held ?

Comment: @StephenG, I meant the 'posture' of the camera on a tripod. I couldn't come up with a better word for this. sorry about the confusion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is properly known as *tilt*. What it means is that the optical axis of the lens is not perpendicular to the plane occupied by the camera's sensor. In your case the entire lens appears to be tilted relative to the camera's lens mounting flange.

Just look at the adapter plate. The right side in the photo is *significantly closer* to the focus ring than the other. With wide aperture wide angle lenses misalignment of as little as [20 microns](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2010/03/this-lens-is-soft-and-other-facts/) can be seen when used with high resolution sensors. In this case we can eyeball the difference from several inches or even feet away! As it sits the lens is flat on the table and the adapter plate is crooked. But once the lens is attached to the camera, the adapter plate will be square with the camera and the lens will be pointing at a slight angle.

[image]

There are specialized lenses that intentionally introduce such angles between the image plane in the camera and the optical axis of the lens. They usually include tilt movements as well as shift movements. Thus they are called *Tilt/Shift* or *Perspective Control* lenses.

Just as an aside, a decentered lens element is, in some ways, similar to a shift movement using a T/S lens. The biggest difference is that all of the elements in a T/S lens are moved together and the various pieces of glass stay in the same alignment with respect to the others. When only one lens element moves in a direction perpendicular to the optical axis of the lens it results in degraded image quality because it is no longer aligned with the other elements in the lens.

You could also get the same result if the camera/lens system is perfectly self aligned but the entire system is improperly aligned with the test chart. The sensor and test chart must be parallel to one another or one side of the chart (or the top, or the bottom, or one of the corners) will be closer to the camera than the other. This will result in only one part of the chart being in focus at any particular focus distance.

For a good explanation of the difference between decentered, tilted, and mis-spaced lens elements (with illustrations) and how to test for each, please see Roger Cicala's excellent blog entry titled: [Testing for a Decentered Lens: an Old Technique Gets a Makeover](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2012/05/testing-for-a-decentered-lens-an-old-technique-gets-a-makeover/)

Comment: "If the tilt is side-to-side, the top and bottom of the image might be fine, but both sides soft. If it is corner-to-corner the top right and lower left corners might be fine, while the top left and lower right are soft." Quoted from Roger Cicala. If you examine the first image closely, you will find the sharpness variation across the image is wired. From the bottom right corner towards the centre is the sharpest area, then comes the top right corner which is a bit softer, bottom left corner considerably softer and the top left corner the softest. Do you think this is still lens tilting?

Comment: Sorry about the accept-undo-accept-accept-undo-accept thing... I accidentally tapped the accept button when scrolling down the page on android app.

Comment: "If the tilt is side-to-side, the top and bottom of the image might be fine, but both sides soft." That depends on where the focus is centered. Roger's statement assumes the center is the most in-focus part of the chart. If the focus is centered to the right of center then the right side would appear to be more in focus than the left. The middle might still be within the acceptable depth of field and appear in focus as well.

Comment: "From the bottom right corner towards the centre is the sharpest area, then comes the top right corner which is a bit softer, bottom left corner considerably softer and the top left corner the softest. Do you think this is still lens tilting?" Yes, it is fairly obviously lens tilting, perhaps also combined with a focusing error. If the area between the lower right corner and the center are the most in focus areas, then the focus was likely correct for the point halfway between the lower right corner and the center. The further one moves from that point, the softer the image gets.

Comment: The other thing one must also consider is that most lenses vary a bit from one side to the other anyway, before tilt is introduced. Any misalignment will be more noticeable on the side that started out softer to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments and answer. I would probably find someone to machine down the focus ring for me first to see if that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Dude, it isn't the focus ring. The adapter is not square to the lens. Can you not see the difference in the size of the gap on the left and on the right?

Comment: Yes, I'm reading your newest edits to your answer.

Comment: After I fully screw the adaptor plate in, I can see there is a small gap at one side while on the other side the M42 flange and the adaptor plate are in contact. Besides, the focus ring is not in contact with the adaptor plate at all. While with other 44-2 lenses, there is no gap between the M42 flange and the plate. The thread on the lens might be bad machined.

Comment: Are you sure the lens (or adapter) is an M42 mount? The T-mount has the same 42mm diameter but the threads are pitched 0.75mm instead of 1.0mm as is the M42.

Comment: I don't think there are T-mount Helios 44-2. The adaptor is definitely M42. Also, if the pitches were different, I don't think I could screw it on.

Comment: That all depends on how hard you're willing to force it! ;-)

Comment: The effort I used to screw it in is the same as I use on other M42 lenses :D